# render json inside js.erb view

Tags: jquery, json, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm trying to add a node to [dynatree](http://wwwendt.de/tech/dynatree/doc/dynatree-doc.html#h8.4.5) via json response, but the question is more general (not the dynatree specific): i can't get how to correctly render json with `.js.erb` into `.html.erb` view

```
#ERB view
 ...
 <div id="places_tree"></div>
 ...
```

```
# controller
def add_places
  @places_json=Place.all.as_json
  respond_to do |format|
    format.js { render layout: false } # execute add_places.js.erb
  end
end
```

```
#add_places.js.erb

var node = $("#places_tree").dynatree("getRoot");
node.addChild(<%= @places_json %>); <=== node not renders into dynatree container `<div id="places_tree"></div>` here
```

if i change it in last row above to pure json

```
node.addChild({"title": 'Title'})
```

node `Title` renders like i expect (node with name Title adds to `<div id="places_tree"></div>`)...

but i need to render `@places_json` dynamically

thanx in advance

Comment: sorry, but i don't understand your problem.

Comment: @phoet i have tried to change some text to make problem more clear.. please, ask if it is still difficult to understand

Comment: Do you see any error in development log or browser's developer console?

Comment: @Nitish it would be easier to solve it i guess =), or i would definitely added it to question. short answer - no. and i think it is just because there is some kind of data format mismatching not machine logic error...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it was too easy to get it quickly

had to make deep debug but i finally discovered the "problem"

1) i have changed `.as_json` to `.to_json` in controller method

2) i have escaped pseudo json string with simple `.html_safe` in `add_places.js.erb`

3) finally, i have made long 'pffffff' sound realizing how simple it was